# CoreData without changes in underlying models

Tags: core-data, migration

Good day,

I have an app with CoreData that is in the Apps Store. I have now coded some 
cosmetic changes in the interface without changing anything in the CoreData model. 
I did not add/delete/or change any entity or property. Now, I am ready to upload my 
version 2 of the app. I am unsure whether I have to do anything so that the old data
of the users in the first version will not be deleted but will be saved in the 
new app (with exactly the same CoreData model). Please be tolerant with this noob.

Great thanks,

Romeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone installs a new version of an app they already have, all the app's data stays where it is-- it doesn't get deleted.

Whether this data is compatible with the new version is a different question. If you haven't made any changes to the data model, then it should be fine. But *you should make sure*. Testing the upgrade process is one of the most important parts of testing a new version of an app. Install the current version, generate some data, and then install your new version and make sure everything looks OK. As you describe it, there shouldn't be any problems, but you should never just trust that this is the case.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your kindness. Do you mean I run the code for the first version in xcode with my iphone connected to install the app in my iphone, then generate some data. After this, run the second version in xcode to install the second version in my iPhone and check the data? Or do you mean create a new adhoc ipa for the first version, install, generate data, then create another adhoc ipa for the second version, install, and check the data? Please excuse my inexperience. Thanks

Comment: Either of those would work. You could also install the old version from the app store and then upgrade to the new version using Xcode. As long as you start with the old version and upgrade to the new version, any method that works is OK.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks a lot. I verified by testing and you are right! Thanks too bastidiasRN

Answer (score 1):

In Marcus Zarra's Core Data Migration Course on iDeveloper TV, he suggests manually locking your xcdatamodel file so that you can't accidentally make updates to it and force a migration when you didn't plan it. But I agree with Tom, test it first.

[iDeveloper.TV Core Data Migration](http://ideveloper.tv/video/coredatamigrationcourse.html)